# How can I get timestamp and Signature for Amazon API?

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, aws-sdk

I'm looking at reading Amazon Api, but I'm not able to read the API as a url and getting the following message "invalid timestamp or signature". How can I get values for both the fields?

Comment: Post some code and/or the url.

Comment: Below is the url I was trying to use to get the product details.http://webservices.amazon.com/onca/xml?
Service=AWSECommerceService&
AWSAccessKeyId=[AWS Access Key ID]&
Operation=ItemLookup&
ItemId=B00008OE6I&
IdType=ASIN&
ResponseGroup=OfferFull&
Condition=All&
Timestamp=[YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssZ]
&Signature=[Request Signature]. In which it is asking for timestamp and signature.

Answer (score 5):

Try to follow the instructions and format here:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/rest-signature.html

The signature is especially the difficult part as it has to be calculated and encoded.
"Calculate an RFC 2104-compliant HMAC with the SHA256 hash algorithm using the string above with our "dummy" Secret Access Key: 1234567890. For more information about this step, see documentation and code samples for your programming language."

The timestamp is generally in this format: UTC time 2009-01-01T12:00:00Z

I would try this api signed requests helper: http://aws.amazon.com/code/Product-Advertising-API/2609

Comment: Thanks for the request helper, did help me to understand the authentication process.

Answer (score 2):

Here I am the providing the code for signing the request .

```
$param = array();
$param['AWSAccessKeyId']   = USER_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID; 
$param['Action']           = 'GetFeedSubmissionList'; 
$param['SellerId']         = USER_MERCHANT_ID; 
$param['SignatureMethod']  = 'HmacSHA256'; 
$param['SignatureVersion'] = '2'; 
$param['Timestamp']        = gmdate("Y-m-d\TH:i:s.\\0\\0\\0\\Z", time()); 
$param['Version']          = '2009-01-01'; 
$param['MarketplaceId']    = USER_MARKETPLACE_ID;  

$url = array();
foreach ($param as $key => $val){

 $key = str_replace("%7E", "~", rawurlencode($key));
 $val = str_replace("%7E", "~", rawurlencode($val));

 $url[] = "{$key}={$val}";
}

sort($url);

$arr   = implode('&', $url);

$sign  = 'GET' . "\n";
$sign .= str_replace("https://","",USER_AMAZON_URL) . "\n";
$sign .= '/' . "\n";
$sign .= $arr;

$signature = hash_hmac("sha256", $sign, USER_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY, true);
$signature = urlencode(base64_encode($signature));

$link  = USER_AMAZON_URL."?";
$link .= $arr . "&Signature=" . $signature;

$data = file_get_contents($link);
```

Comment: Thanks, the encoding part was what I needed in PHP.

Answer (score 2):

This may be a bit late but I just made it work with java:

```
public static String getSignature(String secret, String message) throws Exception {
    Mac sha256_HMAC = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA256");
    SecretKeySpec secret_key = new SecretKeySpec(secret.getBytes(), "HmacSHA256");
    sha256_HMAC.init(secret_key);

    String hash = Base64.encodeBase64String(sha256_HMAC.doFinal(message.getBytes()));
    hash = URLEncoder.encode(hash, "UTF-8");

    return hash;
}
```

The only library needed is `apache commons-codec`